# How can I make my menu work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using a javascrpit menu for my website. The user clicks the guitar in the top left corner to display the menu. This works on all browsers so far and on mobile devices, except for desktop Chrome. When the guitar is clicked, the menu flashes up and dissappears. Anyone have any ideas why?

the website is www.fiveextras.co.uk

I have included to code for the script just for reference.

```
<!--define the element that will be used to start the menu-->
<a href="#" id="designanchor">
<div id="nav"><img src="images/guitarnav.png" width="100"
height="103" alt="navigation"/></div>
</a>


<div id="mymenu1" class="outlinemenu">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><h3>About Us</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="media.html"><h3>Media</h3></a></li>
<li><a href=""><h3>News</h3></a></li>
<li><a href=""><h3>Contact Us</h3></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
jkoutlinemenu.definemenu("designanchor", "mymenu1", "click", 180)
</script>
```

Comment: I removed "java" from your title, because you're using *JavaScript*, which is entirely different from *Java*. They are completely separate and unrelated languages.

Comment: Yes thanks, must have been a slip of the mouse as I am very aware of the difference

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.91 m

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. It was a hyperlink misbeahving that was only picked up on chrome. Many thanks for taking to time to look though

Comment: Either delete this question, or post your answer.

Comment: Maybeyou could try asking me to, rather than telling me to.